# AddNew Function using Linked List In C

Tags: c, linked-list

**Question:** Create a linked list containing values in the ascending values. Then write functions `addNew()` which will accept a value from the user and then call `addBegin()` and `addafterValue()` functions to add the input value in the appropriate place

e.g. consider the list is like this:
`12,15,20,26` then if the user enters values `8, 16 & 30` the list will look like this: `8,12,15,16,20,26,30`.

My program:

```
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
}NODE;

NODE *start=NULL;

void append()
{
    NODE *temp,*ptr;
    temp=(NODE *)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    printf("Enter data:");
    scanf("%d",&temp->data);
    temp->next=NULL;
    if(start==NULL)
        start=temp;
    else
    {
        ptr=start;
        while(ptr->next!=NULL)
            ptr=ptr->next;
        ptr->next=temp;
    }
}

void display()
{
    NODE *ptr=start;
    while(ptr!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d\n",ptr->data);
        ptr=ptr->next;
    }
}

void addBegin(int val)
{
    NODE *temp;
    temp=(NODE *)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    temp->data=val;
    temp->next=start;
    start=temp;
}

unsigned int addAfterValue(int val,NODE *ptr)
{
    NODE *temp;
    temp=(NODE *)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    temp->data=val;
    temp->next=ptr->next;
    return temp;
}

void addNew()
{
    int val;
    unsigned int loc;
    NODE *ptr=start;
    printf("Enter value to add:");
    scanf("%d",&val);
    if(val<ptr->data) {
        addBegin(val);
        ptr=NULL;
    }
    while(ptr!=NULL) {
        if(ptr->next!=NULL)
        {
            if(val<ptr->next->data)
            {
                addAfterValue(val,ptr);
                ptr->next=loc;
                ptr=NULL;
            }
            else
            {
                ptr=ptr->next;
            }
        }
        if(ptr->next==NULL)
        {
            loc=addAfterValue(val,ptr);
            ptr=NULL;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int ans;
    do
    {
        printf("Enter [1]To append\n[2]To add new node\n[3]To display\n[0]To exit\n");
        printf("Enter your choice:");
        scanf("%d",&ans);
        switch(ans)
        {
            case 1:
                append();
                break;
            case 2:
                addNew();
                break;
            case 3:
                display();
                break;
            case 0:
                break;
            default:
                printf("Wrong Input.Try again.");
        }
    }while(ans);
}
```

**My doubt:** The `addBegin()` function works perfectly. I think there's something wrong with `addafterValue()`. Can anyone help me by finding out my mistake?

Comment: Why do you think there is something wrong with your addafterValue? Did you test out your code? If you feel there is something wrong, create some test cases. If one of them is wrong, then use a debugger and step through it.

Comment: You are breaking the list in that function. New node's next pointer is assigned but the existing previous node is not pointed to the new node.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing the current pointer address.
Use the previous node pointer and assign to its next node.

```
void addAfterValue(int val,NODE *ptr)
{
    NODE *temp = (NODE *)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    temp->data=val;
    temp->next=ptr->next;
    ptr->next = temp;
}
```

Change the addNew function

```
void addNew()
{ 
    int val;
    NODE *ptr=start;
    NODE *prev= NULL;
    printf("Enter value to add:");
    scanf("%d",&val);

    if( ptr == NULL || val < ptr->data)
    {
         addBegin(val);
         return;
    }
    else
    {
         prev = ptr;
         ptr=ptr->next;
    }

    while( ptr != NULL)
    { 
            if( val <= ptr->data)
            {
                addAfterValue(val,prev);
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                prev = ptr;
                ptr=ptr->next;

            }
    }

    /* Control comes here if the entire list is scanned.... Now append it to the end using prev pointer, as the new node is greater than all of the existing nodes */

}
```